# Group validation doesn't work using ldap_authenticatable

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Trying to build group validation. But it doesn't let me log in to my app.

**Here's WEBrick output:**

```
LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: uid=my_name
LDAP: LDAP search for login: uid=my_name
LDAP: LDAP search yielded 2 matches
LDAP: Authorizing user uid=my_name,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
LDAP: Not authorized because not in required groups.
```

In my devise.rb file *config.ldap_check_group_membership* &  *config.ldap_ad_group_check* are set as true.

**ldap.yml:**

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
allow_unauthenticated_bind: false
group_base: cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
required_groups:
- cn=noc,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
```

**Using ldapsearch command I checked that my ldap tree looks like that:**

`# noc, groups, accounts, aws.company.net
    dn: cn=noc,cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    member: uid=b..,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    member: uid=my_name,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    member: uid=i...,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    member: uid=n...,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    member: uid=s...,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    member: uid=e...,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=aws,dc=company,dc=net
    objectClass: top
    objectClass: groupofnames
    objectClass: nestedgroup
    objectClass: ipausergroup
    objectClass: ipaobject
    objectClass: posixgroup
    objectClass: ipantgroupattrs
    description: noc operators group
    cn: noc`

Please can somebody point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Someone please help me with this, any ideas? Nobody ever faced that??